# How to subString based on the special character?

Tags: java

I have String like below ,I want to get subString If any special character is there.

```
 String myString="Regular $express&ions are <patterns <that can@ be %matched against *strings";
```

I want out like below

```
       express
       inos
       patterns
       that
       matched
      Strings
```

Any one help me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: If any special character is there I want that word in the String ,I have to use this in my project.

Comment: Why there is no `can` (based on `can@`) in result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note:*** as @MaxZoom pointed out, it seems that I didn't understand the OP's problem properly. The OP apparently does not want to split the string on special characters, but rather keep the words starting with a special character. The former is adressed by my answer, the latter by @MaxZoom's answer.

---

You should take a look at the [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method.

Give it a regexp matching all the characters you want, and you'll get an array of all the strings you want. For instance:

```
String myString = "Regular $express&ions are <patterns <that can@ be %matched against *strings";
String[] words = myString.split("[$&<@%*]");
```

Comment: An implementation provided along with the answer would be cool

Comment: @KalyanChavali Yep, it was ongoing ;-) Though, I usually prefer not to give everything to the OP in this kind of homework/projetc/school question.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Joffrey ,

Comment: This solution will create an array with not needed words, such as `Regular, are, be` which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @MaxZoom you're right, I hadn't properly understood the OP's objective. But then I don't understand why he accepted my answer now, this is strange :/

Comment: Thank you to be honest. Lets ask him when he is back .

Comment: @MaxZoom No problem, we're here to answer people's questions, and it does not hurt my pride to have missed the point in the OP's requirement, it happens to anyone ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This regex will select words that starts with special character:

```
[$&<%*](\w*)
```

explanation:

```
[$&<%*] match a single character present in the list below
   $&<%* a single character in the list $&<%* literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing group (\w*)
  \w* match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
   Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aY7bM6/1)

> MATCH 1  [9-16]   `express`
>   MATCH 2  [17-21]  `ions`
>   MATCH 3  [27-35]  `patterns`
>   MATCH 4  [37-41]  `that`
>   MATCH 5  [51-58]  `matched`
>   MATCH 6  [68-75]  `strings`

Solution in Java code:

```
String str = "Regular $express&ions are <patterns <that can@ be %matched against *strings";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[$&<%*](\\w*)").matcher(str);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
  words.add(matcher.group(1));
}
System.out.println(words.toString());

// prints [express, ions, patterns, that, matched, strings]
```